# How to get element from return statement with sls file

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following line in an .sls file, but it always seems to succeed whatever server I put in there:

```
{% if salt['network.connect']('server.network.com', 80).result == True -%}
```

When I run `salt-call --local network.connect server.network.com 80` I get the following output:

```
local:
----------
comment:
    Unable to connect to server.network.com on tcp port 80
result:
    False
```

The result is structured.
How can I get to `result` in the sls state above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the `== True`.

I tested these both:

```
{% if salt['network.connect']('server.network.com', 80).result %}
```

as well as the inverse:

```
{% if not salt['network.connect']('server.network.com', 80).result %}
```